# Schizophrenia relation between brain theta wave or kundalini and

Tags: brain-waves

Is there a connection between the Kundalini force and the brain waves in relation to the question-based meditation link below?

[Which Meditation Techniques Correlate Best with Certain Brain-Waves?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17829/23404)

And what are the characteristics of the brain theta wave, besides is there a link between the illusions of schizophrenia and the increase in theta waves in the brain? And what if there is a new science in place of the Kundalini force instead of what they have said?

Link to an Amateur Talk about Kundalini and Schizophrenia on YouTube:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-G0S6s7DGKU

I found this paper with this topic:

**Schizophrenia or spiritual crisis? On "raising the kundalini" and its diagnostic classification**

> Two patients are described who had been diagnosed as schizophrenic,
>   but had actually instead been going through spiritual crises, which in
>   Eastern spiritual tradition are called raising the kundalini. Perhaps
>   this experience is not a disease, but many--especially if not
>   understood by oneself, the nearest relations and the medical
>   profession--cause mental illness. In WHO ICD-10 the experience could
>   be classified as F48.8, disordines neurotici specificati alii. The
>   process falls outside the categories of both normal and psychotic.
>   When allowed to progress to completion this process culminates in deep
>   psychological balance, strength, and maturity.

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback on this research data.

Comment: Based on my experience in meditation, better not to think about developing kundalini if schizophrenia is not cured. This mental disease will be cured with Metta or loving-kindness.